# Where is the subject for this to infinitive?

Tags: subjects

> "We wondered who Dumbledore had trusted enough **to help** him, apart
>   from you."
>
> (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

Is there no need to put subject of *to help*, for example, for them? Is the fore-shifted who is the semantic subject of *to help*?

Comment: You got it. Dumbledore trusted X to help him, and we wondered who X was.

Comment: Infinitives don't have a subject.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Sure they do. I urge **you to consider** this sentence. Dumbledore trusted **somebody to help** him. The subject may serve [other functions](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf) as well, but it's still the subject of the infinitive.

Comment: @StoneyB It's not _You to consider this sentence._ _I_ is the subject for _urge_, not _to consider_.

Comment: @kiamlaluno But "you" is the subject of the subordinate clause "you to consider this sentence", just as it is in "I urge that you consider the map".

Comment: @kiamlaluno 'doh! I meant of course "that you consider this sentence".

Comment: @stoney Maybe, but by that logic in the sentence "I conducted the experiment to learn more about the subject," "the experiment" is the subject of the subordinate clause rather than the object of "I conducted", thereby leaving the transitive verb "conduct" without an object.

Comment: @BobRodes 1) I don't mean to imply that **all** infinitives have subjects; *to do so would be an error.* 2) A single constituent may serve two functions. In your sentence, the subject of *learn* is also the subject of *conduct*, "I"; in *Dumbledore trusted somebody to help him*, the object of *trust* is also the subject of *help*. See [this](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
               [Dumbledore had trusted X enough to help him].
Who was X?                             ↓
              ← ← ← ← ← ← ← ← ← ← ← ← ↵
             ↓
           [who Dumbledore had trusted _ enough to help him]
We wondered who Dumbledore had trusted   enough to help him.
```

Note that *Dumbledore trusted X enough to help him* is ambiguous. It may mean either:

> Dumbledore had sufficient trust in X [for Dumbledore to help X] *OR*
>   Dumbledore had sufficient trust in X [that X would help Dumbledore].

But context makes clear what is meant.